# struggling to understand "List<String> list = people.stream().map(Person::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());"

Tags: java, list, dictionary, java-stream

I was reading Oracle Java Tutorial on List interface and have encountered the following syntax:

```
List<String> list = people.stream().map(Person::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

the tutorial only mentioned that it is an example that aggregates some names into a List but did not explain it any further. I have been struggling to understand how this statement actually works. Could someone please explain it to me?

Comment: That's too broad. If you don't understand anything at all, study. If there's something specific, be specific.

Comment: What don't you understand? Do you understand how streams work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The first method, [`people.stream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--) creates a [`Stream<Person>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html).
- A transformation is specified by [`map()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-). Each `Person` in the stream will be converted to a `String` by invoking `getName()` on it. The `Person::getName` syntax is a "method reference", and has a type of [`Function<Person,String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) in this case. The result is a `Stream<String>`.
- A `Collector<String,?,List<String>>` is created, using the factory method [`Collectors.toList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--).
- The [`collect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) method is a terminal operation; invoking it causes the `Stream` to be evaluated. The results are collected, producing a new `List<String>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> list =
people.stream() // gets a Stream<Person> 
    .map(Person::getName) // for each Person object call the getName() method - producing a Stream<String> of the result of that method call
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); // collect that Stream<String> into a List, which is stored in the local variable declared as list
```

This can be written imperatively as

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (Person person : people) {
    list.add(person.getName());
}
```

Comment: If Java's streams take advantage of the lazy behavior, the 2 won't always act identically, but for all intent and purposes here, they're equivalent.